# Ruby IF statement with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if subject.downcase.include? product.name.downcase || body.downcase.include? product.name.downcase
  puts "111"
end
```

Why is the above faulty in ruby? Is there a better way to write this?

This is the resulting error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
... body.downcase.include? product.name.downcase
...                               ^
(irb):9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: Not related to question, but another implementation of this is to use Regexp.

Comment: if subject =~ /#{product.name}/i || body =~ /#{product.name}/i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translates to:

```
if subject.downcase.include? (product.name.downcase || body.downcase.include? product.name.downcase)
```

You need to add parentheses:

```
if subject.downcase.include?(product.name.downcase) || body.downcase.include? product.name.downcase
```

However probably this is more readable:

```
if [subject, body].any? {|element| element.downcase.include? product.name.downcase}
```